# Improve video seek/display performance?

Tags: video, html5-video

I have an animation use-case where I need to play the video with javascript, by setting the currentTime property.

I provided here a very simple use-case.

Depending on the video size/encoding etc, I noticed that the "seeking" time(**the time that passes since I set the currentTime till the frame is displayed**), can vary very much, from a few ms to a few hundred ms.

Are there any ways to improve this?

Tweaks, players or any ideas are welcome!

https://codepen.io/klodoma/pen/YmZjpx

```
seeking: 139.93994140625ms
seeking: 127.566162109375ms
seeking: 139.966796875ms
seeking: 136.269287109375ms
seeking: 144.666259765625ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to find an absolute answer hard to find here as there are so many factors involved.

In very general terms the more complex and efficient the encoder the more likely it is that any given frame can only be generated and displayed with help from some proceeding and possibly following frames.

This means that when the player seeks to the frame closest to the time you are inputting, the player needs to identify the group or set of frames it needs to display your frame, plus whatever it needs to buffer to provide the playback 'smoothness' it targets.

You could try to second guess by using simpler codecs or testing to see which encoding works best, but different players, platform or decoding SW or HW may have optiomizations that are hard to predict, and may also change as they are upgraded.

The delay range you are seeing at the moment is actually quite impressive - I am surprised you are not seeing longer delays sometimes.